# If n is multiple of 4, what is the rest of the division by 10?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to resolve this issue about congruence / module, but I have no idea where to start. Can anybody help me?

If n is a multiple of 4, what is the rest of the division of $1^n + 2^n +....+ 8^n + 9^n$ by 10?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use Euler's thoerem of congruence

Comment: Technically, Euler's theorem requires base coprime to the modulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^{4m}$ ends with $1$, $2^{4m}$ ends with $6$, $3^{4m}$ ends with $1$, $4^{4m}$ ends with $6$, and $5^{5m}$ ends with $5$.

$(10-k)^{4n}$ ends with the same digit as $k^{4n}$.

Therefore, your sum ends with the same digit as $1+6+1+6+5+6+1+6+1$ does,

which is $3$.

Comment: Thank you for your he.lp

Comment: You’re welcome.  $1$, $5$, $6$, and $0$ are idempotents modulo $10$